# editing HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an html file which I edited because there was a typo . I tried to make a corresponding change to the .php file but these changes are not getting rid of Undefined Index notice I am getting. If I instead edit the .php file to match the typo in html, the error does not appear. What is going on?

html code:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Guardian Title</dt>
  <dd>
    <input id="G_Title" name="G_Title" type="text" />
  </dd>
</dl>
```

php code

```
$G_Title  =     $_POST['G_title'];
```

If I change php to `G_Title` everything is fine but if I change html to `G_Title`, I still get the error.

Of course, I can see the work around right here, but why does this error come about?

Comment: just make sure this `G_Title` in PHP: `$_POST['G_title'];` and this `G_Title` in HTML: `name="G_Title"` are written exactly the same, and you should be fine

Comment: What does your code look like when you get the undefined index error? Were you getting the error before you changed the typo? I'm not sure if the code you posted has the error or not because from what you posted it looks like the only typo is in the php which you said works if you change it to G_Title instead of G_title, the html you posted already contains G_Title as one would expect.

Comment: thnx it worked when I made the changes advised by  x4rf4 and refreshed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `G_Title` in the HTML and `G_title` in the PHP. Make sure the case matches on both.

Change your HTML to:

```html
<input id="G_title" name="G_title" type="text" />
```

*Or* change your PHP to:

```php
$G_Title  =     $_POST['G_Title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct PHP code :

```
$G_Title  =     $_POST['G_Title'];
```

To avoid this error in the future, don't use capital letters in your code.